# Swift 2: Natively serialize JSON to Core Data Model Objects

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization, swifty-json

I would like to serialize JSON into Core Data Model Objects, and back and forth.   I am in the process of switching from RestKIT to Alamofire and Swifty JSON.   I know there are libraries that provide that, but I would like to know how to do it natively?

Below is the Core Data Setup:

[image]

Event+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Event {

    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var realRame: String?
    @NSManaged var notes: NSSet?

}
```

Event.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Event: NSManagedObject {
// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass
}
```

Notes+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Notes {

    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var event: Event?

}
```

Notes.swift

import Foundation
import CoreData

class Notes: NSManagedObject {
// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass
}

Below is received JSON:

```
{
    "id": "5555",
    "name": "Superman",
    "realName": "Clark Kent",
    "notes": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Order Flowers"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Pick up Laundry"
        }
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Get Chinese Food"
        },
    ]
}
```

Code to fetch the JSON:

```
Alamofire.request(fetchData(param)).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Question:  I'm not sure where to go from here.  `NSJSONSerialization` seems to want the data in `NSData` format.

Code example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are getting response in JSON, then you can directly store it in NSMutableDictionary and access value using key value pair. Why do you need to use  NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: I'm using SwiftyJSON to convert from JSON to Objects. How do I go back words?

Answer (score 0):

Add new class DBManager:

```
class DBManager: NSObject {
var managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext!
var managedObjectModel:NSManagedObjectModel!

func insertData(jsonObj: AnyObject)  {
            let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Event",
                                                     in:managedObjectContext)
            let obj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                           insertInto: managedObjectContext)

            obj.setValue(String((jsonObj.value(forKey: "id"))!)  , forKey: "id")

....
```

Continue setting values for other attributes.

Declare this var in AppDelegate:

```
var objDb = DBManager()
```

Add this

```
switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)

                let anyObjects: AnyObject = json as! AnyObject
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.objDb.insertData(jsonObj: anyObjects)
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
```